# Failing SamConnect, SamOpenDomain, SamrQueryInformationDomain failing to link

Tags: winapi, win32-process

I have windows c++ application for fetching password complexity
somehow it is failing with linker error
Not able find documented header by msdn, even I copy the function declaration it is failing with linker error, may be possibly function signature mismatch of libs function. I do not find function signature from lib in Windows kits.

```
1>obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl SamQueryInformationDomain(void *,enum _DOMAIN_INFORMATION_CLASS,void * *)" (?SamQueryInformationDomain@@YAJPEAXW4_DOMAIN_INFORMATION_CLASS@@PEAPEAX@Z)
 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl SamOpenDomain(void *,unsigned long,void *,void * *)" (?SamOpenDomain@@YAJPEAXK0PEAPEAX@Z)
 
 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl SamConnect(struct _LSA_UNICODE_STRING *,void * *,unsigned long,unsigned char)" (?SamConnect@@YAJPEAU_LSA_UNICODE_STRING@@PEAPEAXKE@Z)
 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl SamCloseHandle(void *)" (?SamCloseHandle@@YAJPEAX@Z)
```

but these functions are present in lib file, checked with dumpbin

```
#pragma comment(lib, "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.19041.0\\um\\x64\\samlib.lib")

NTSTATUS SamQueryInformationDomain(SAMPR_HANDLE domain, DOMAIN_INFORMATION_CLASS val, PSAMPR_DOMAIN_INFO_BUFFER* Buffer);
extern NTSTATUS WINAPI SamConnect(IN PUNICODE_STRING ServerName, OUT SAMPR_HANDLE* ServerHandle, IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess, IN BOOLEAN Trusted);
extern NTSTATUS WINAPI SamOpenDomain(IN SAMPR_HANDLE SamHandle, IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess, IN PSID DomainId, OUT SAMPR_HANDLE* DomainHandle);
extern NTSTATUS WINAPI SamCloseHandle(IN SAMPR_HANDLE SamHandle);

void ReadPasswordComplexInfo()
{
    NTSTATUS status, enumDomainStatus, enumUserStatus;
    UNICODE_STRING serverName;
    ACCESS_MASK mask = 0;
    mask = SAM_SERVER_CONNECT | SAM_SERVER_ENUMERATE_DOMAINS | SAM_SERVER_LOOKUP_DOMAIN;
    SAMPR_HANDLE hServerHandle, hBuiltinHandle = NULL, hDomainHandle, hUserHandle;
    DWORD domainEnumerationContext = 0, domainCountRetourned, userEnumerationContext, userCountRetourned, groupsCountRetourned, i, j, k, aliasCountRetourned, *alias;
    PSAMPR_RID_ENUMERATION pEnumDomainBuffer, pEnumUsersBuffer;
    PSID domainSid, userSid;
    PGROUP_MEMBERSHIP pGroupMemberShip;

    //PSAMPR_DOMAIN_INFO_BUFFER *buff = NULL;
    PSAMPR_DOMAIN_INFO_BUFFER buff;
    SID builtin = {SID_REVISION, 1, SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY, {SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID}};

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&serverName, L"");
    
    //status = SamConnect(&serverName, &hServerHandle, SAM_SERVER_CONNECT | SAM_SERVER_ENUMERATE_DOMAINS | SAM_SERVER_LOOKUP_DOMAIN, FALSE);
    status = SamConnect(&serverName, &hServerHandle, SAM_SERVER_CONNECT | SAM_SERVER_ENUMERATE_DOMAINS | SAM_SERVER_LOOKUP_DOMAIN, FALSE);
    if (0 != status)
    {
        printf("SamConnect error (?) %08x\n", status);
        return;
    }

    //status = SamOpenDomain(hServerHandle, DOMAIN_LIST_ACCOUNTS | DOMAIN_LOOKUP, &builtin, &hBuiltinHandle);
    status = SamOpenDomain(hServerHandle, DOMAIN_LIST_ACCOUNTS | DOMAIN_LOOKUP, domainSid, &hDomainHandle);
    if (0 != status)
    {
        printf("SamOpenDomain Builtin (?) %08x\n", status);
        return;
    }

    //status = SamQueryInformationDomain(hBuiltinHandle, DomainPasswordInformation, (PVOID*)&buff);
    status = SamrQueryInformationDomain(hBuiltinHandle, DomainPasswordInformation, (PVOID*)&buff);
    if (0 != status)
    {
        printf("SamQueryInformation failed with %08x\n", status);
    }ULONG properties = buff->Password.PasswordProperties; printf("SamQueryInformation success with password properties value : %ld\n", properties);
    if(hBuiltinHandle)
    {
        SamCloseHandle(hBuiltinHandle);
        SamCloseHandle(hServerHandle);
    }
}
```

Also tried with SamrOpenDomain API same issues.

Comment: You are compiling a 32-bit target but instruct the linker to link against a 64-bit import library. You're also seemingly trying to import symbols with C++ name decorations. You'll need to fix that, too. Since we cannot see your function declarations, we cannot help you with that.

Comment: edited added declarations. I am compiling and linking with Release x64 configuration VS2019

Comment: Difficult to make sure since there are lots of missing pieces here, but surrounding the Sam* definitions by `extern "C" { *definitions goes here* }` should be enough.

Comment: `extern "C"` should take care of the name decoration issues. You may also want to replace the import library pragma with `#pragma comment(lib, "samlib.lib")`, so that your code remains target platform agnostic.

Comment: also you need use `SamQueryInformationDomain` (withour **r**)

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for suggestion, this worked it was name decoration issue.
One query I had in mind, this lib is part of Windows kits, but header is not included as part of any SDK, is it something that Microsoft does not support anymore now
Or some other SDk needed for this  etc.
Did find any OS version from which this supported
RbMm yeah I was playing around both versions with/without r

Comment: The fact it's not documented and not in the headers and has never been means Microsoft has never supported it.

Comment: never need *playing*. need understand what you doing. *SamQueryInformationDomain* is exported by *samlib.dll* - this is client dll and can be used in any process. *SamrQueryInformationDomain* is exported by *samsrv.dll* which is loaded only inside *lsass.exe* process. you can use this dll only in case you write dll which is loaded in lsass.exe too (for instance sspi/ap dll)

Comment: @RbMm So SamrQueryInformationDomain documentation publicly available means we can use it. where as the other one SamQueryInformationDomain is not available publicly documented we should not be using

Comment: no. you must use `SamQueryInformationDomain` . you can use `SamrQueryInformationDomain` only in case you inside lsass.exe. are you understand my previous comment ?

Comment: yes I understood your comment, what I am asking is SamQueryInformationDomain is undocumented, from previous comments  it seems MS never supported it. So you still recommond to use undocumented "SamQueryInformationDomain"

Comment: i dont know what is *undocumented* and *never supported*. i know that is use *SamQueryInformationDomain* is correct choice.

Comment: also `SamFreeMemory(buff );` must be and buff declared as `PDOMAIN_PASSWORD_INFORMATION buff;`

Comment: I found msdn documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-samr/4df07fab-1bbc-452f-8e92-7853a3c7e380?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: this documentation about protocol but not about exactly api. you need understand that exist 2 different dll/api implementation. the *samsrv.dll* live in lsass.exe and do final processing. the documentation about it api. but if you not inside lsass process - you use another dll - samlib.dll . this dll can be loaded to any process. and you need use it api (if you not in lsass) this dll was proxy by fact. all it api do remote call to lsass process. but it have different names and sometime signature. `samlib.SamQueryInformationDomain -> samsrv.SamrQueryInformationDomain`